# Accessing data in nested ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, json, win-universal-app, expandoobject

I have the following code:

```
        string responJsonText = "{'A609C5DC-E86A-11E5-BD37-3EF25AFC4F71': {'username': 'testuser1','mydata1': 52,'mydata2': 1,'mydata3': '+1889','lastupdate': '2016-03-21 11:49:28'},'C5DD67C5-F34B-34DC-DB67-4F5376BD7813': {'username': 'testuser2','mydata1': 52.7,'mydata2': 1.5,'mydata3': '+2373','lastupdate': '2016-03-20 14:38:28'}}"; 
        //data usually retrieved from web service
        dynamic response = new ExpandoObject();
        response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(responJsonText);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in response)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp2 in kvp.Value as ExpandoObject) 
                Debug.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", kvp2.Key, kvp2.Value);
        }
```

As you can see it iterates through each json object and then through the inner objects.

However I would like to use something more simple such as follows but cannot get my head around it:

```
//Just an example
foreach (var item in response) 
{
   Debug.WriteLine(item.username);
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot ways to get the `username` in your `responJsonText`. One simple approach is [Querying JSON with LINQ](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) like following:

```
string responJsonText = "{'A609C5DC-E86A-11E5-BD37-3EF25AFC4F71': {'username': 'testuser1','mydata1': 52,'mydata2': 1,'mydata3': '+1889','lastupdate': '2016-03-21 11:49:28'},'C5DD67C5-F34B-34DC-DB67-4F5376BD7813': {'username': 'testuser2','mydata1': 52.7,'mydata2': 1.5,'mydata3': '+2373','lastupdate': '2016-03-20 14:38:28'}}";

JObject o = JObject.Parse(responJsonText);
var children = o.Children().Children()["username"].Values<string>();

foreach (var item in children)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Or using [SelectToken with JSONPath](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) like:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(responJsonText);
IEnumerable<JToken> names = o.SelectTokens("$..username");

foreach (var item in names)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(item);
}
```